# python, zipfile | как запаковать папку без абсолютного пути

Tags: python, ос, zipfile

Всем добрый день, есть вопросик. У меня есть такой код:

```
for folder, subfolders, files in os.walk(rf"{Путь до папки}"):
    for file in files:
        new_zip_file.write(os.path.join(folder, file),
               os.path.relpath(os.path.join(folder, file)), compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
```

Проблема в том, что он добавляет в архив абсолютный путь, а мне нужно чтобы было добавлялась папка с файлами. Как решить проблему?

Comment: Нужен минимальный пример, который воспроизводит проблему.

Comment: У меня указывается путь к папке, к файлам и папкам к которой применяется скрипт которых архивирует всё. С файлами все ок, но папка почему-то добавляется с родильными папками 
https://ibb.co/qCJWnbH

Comment: Вот полный код, https://pastebin.com/nGrB7bd6

Comment: [ZipFile.write](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.write) поддерживает аргумент `arcname` которы сделает то что вам нужно.